# DrumBoiler Modeling in Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I want to get into modeling with `modelica` especially the `thermial` and `fluid` branches. So now I am reversing and altering examples from stackoverflow and the `modelica` library to get to know the language better.

At the moment I try to understand `Modelica.Fluid.Examples.DrumBoiler.DrumBoiler`. I have no problems to comprehend what the model does physically. But when I rebuilt it, I get the error message:

> Function Cv.from_bar not found in scope DrumBoiler.

I rebuild the model from scratch and I copied the example from the library. Both the same problem.
The problem lies here:

```
Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary sink(
nPorts = 1, 
p = Cv.from_bar(0.5), <-- problem
redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWaterOnePhase, 
T = 500)
```

In order to define the starting (?) pressure of the sink, a function is called. But the function was not defined anywhere. And yet the model works when I simulate it from the library, but it does not when I copy it from there.

What am I missing?
I am using OMedit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is here: `Modelica.SIunits.Conversions.from_bar`. You can use `import` to import it, or `import Cv = Modelica.SIunits.Conversions` to import it under the shorter alias name `Cv`.

You can also read more about importing here:

- https://mbe.modelica.university/components/packages/nimport
- https://mbe.modelica.university/components/packages/importing

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I know about the import feature, but in the original modelica example there is no import of SIunits. But the function works anyway. I want to know how that works. Becaus when I copy the eyample the code doesn't work.

Comment: It is sufficient to import in the top level, and it will be available in all levels below. So probably the import was not in the example itself, but in some higher level package.

Comment: two levels up! Great, thank you. That explaines, why the model did not run when i copied it.