# Broken Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveIncompressible model? Receiving error "Function Utilities.regRoot2 not found in scope <X>"

Tags: compiler-errors, fluid, openmodelica

I have created a model of a three-way valve based upon 2 two-way valves, which are declared as replaceable models. Here is its incipit...

```
within SHCLibrary;
model ThreeWayBallValveII

// Import section, AKA nicknames section. To (greately) improve readability.
  import Modelica.Fluid.System;
  import Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.{FluidPort_a, FluidPort_b};
  import Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant;
  import Modelica.Blocks.Math.Add;
  import Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput;

// Definition of the fluid to be used in the component.
//  replaceable package Medium = Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium;
  replaceable package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.ConstantPropertyLiquidWater;
// Allows for optional redefinition of junciton and valves model. 
//  replaceable model TeeJunction = Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.BaseClasses.PartialTeeJunction;
  replaceable model TeeJunction = Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.TeeJunctionIdeal;
//  replaceable model Valve = Modelica.Fluid.Valves.BaseClasses.PartialValve;
  replaceable model Valve = Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear;
//  replaceable model Valve = Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveIncompressible;
//  import Valve = Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveIncompressible;

...
```

I am using this valve in its test model modifying the `Valve` declaration. The point is that if I use the `LinearValve` model everything goes well.

```
  ThreeWayBallValveII V1(
   redeclare package Medium = Medium,
   redeclare model Valve = Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear)
   annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
```

Instead, If I use the `ValveIncompressible` model

```
  ThreeWayBallValveII V1(
   redeclare package Medium = Medium,
//   redeclare model Valve = Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear)
   redeclare model Valve = Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveIncompressible)
   annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
```

I get this error:

```
[1] 12:40:08 Translation Error
[Modelica.Fluid.Valves: 38:9-40:80]: Function Utilities.regRoot2 not found in scope Valve.
```

I think this could be solved by adding a line like this

```
      import Modelica.Fluid.Utilities;
```

to the `ValveIncompressible` model in the `Valves` package, but it seems strange to me that this has not yet been fixed before and I am wondering it I am doing something wrong. What do you think?

Sincerely,

Comment: realted/similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749708/drumboiler-modeling-in-modelica

Comment: Thank you matth. I have filed this bug to the OpenModelica team [here](https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/5904) along with the source code to replicate the problem. I think this is different from the other one in that I have tried to create the model from scratch, not copying some internal code of the library, and this code is correctly handled by Dymola.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `import Modelica.Fluid.Utilities;` is required in the file `Modelica 3.2.3/Fluid/Valves.mo`. On my machine the beginning of the class in question now reads:

```
within Modelica.Fluid;
package Valves "Components for the regulation and control of fluid flow"
    extends Modelica.Icons.VariantsPackage;

    model ValveIncompressible "Valve for (almost) incompressible fluids"
      extends BaseClasses.PartialValve;
      import Modelica.Fluid.Types.CvTypes;
      import Modelica.Constants.pi;
      import Modelica.Fluid.Utilities;

      constant SI.ReynoldsNumber Re_turbulent = 4000
      "cf. straight pipe for fully open valve -- dp_turbulent increases for closing valve";
      parameter Boolean use_Re = system.use_eps_Re
      "= true, if turbulent region is defined by Re, otherwise by m_flow_small"
        annotation(Dialog(tab="Advanced"), Evaluate=true);
...
```

With this modification my model works.